# Inserting an array of user defined types into Cassandra using gocql

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

I have a UDT in Cassandra and I have a table that has an array of these UDTs in its schema. Here's a sample:

```
CREATE TYPE keyspace.test_type(
    x float, 
    y float)
```

In my schema I have

```
 CREATE TABLE test_table(
     key text,
     test_array list<FROZEN <test_type>>,
     PRIMARY KEY (key))
```

Inside my go package I built a struct:

```
type Test_type struct{
     x float32
     y float32
}
```

Then I have a function that essentially returns a list of this test_type: `[]test_type`, let's call it `my_array`.

When I try to do the insert using gocql like such:

```
 err := gocql.Session.Query('INSERT into test_table (key,test_array)
                             VALUES (?,?)', 'key', my_array).Exec()
```

I get a bunch of null values instead of my array. Essentially the test_type does not correctly map to the UDT that I created is my assumption.

Essentially my question is how do you map a struct in go to a udt such that the type is recognized properly. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per: [Converting Go struct to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270816/converting-go-struct-to-json)

The problem was resolved by renaming the fields so it exports. That way gocql can see the data type x & y.

Simply renaming `x`to `X` and `y` to `Y`. Will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it isn't important, but I have read on https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html that it isn't

`CREATE TABLE test_table(
     key text,
     test_array list<FROZEN test_type>>,
     PRIMARY KEY (key))`

but

`CREATE TABLE test_table(
     key text,
     test_array list<FROZEN <test_type>>,
     PRIMARY KEY (key))`

the correct definition of the table. I haven't the way to try your code, tell me if it change something.

An other thing that I have read is in [Update a collection type of a custom type in cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662850/update-a-collection-type-of-a-custom-type-in-cassandra) 
I think you should define your custom type in Cassandra, because you have a list of custom type.

Comment: Hey, you are correct..This was a syntax error on my part. Take a look at the answer that I posted. The change I suggest there correctly wrote the data into Cassandra :)

Comment: I have seen. My doubt now is about the definition of the type. Why have you declared test_type with x and y as float in Cassandra? Aren't they maps in Golang?

Comment: You can do that as well. However, in my use case I wanted to represent it as a struct instead of a map.